# Borel--Bott--Weil for the Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, vector-bundles, flag-varieties

The Borel--Bott--Weil Theorem is usually stated for the complete flag manifold of $SU(N)$. Does an analogue hold for the other flags, for example the Grassmannians?

More precisely, suppose $G(\mathbf C)$ is a complex reductive group, and $P(\mathbf C)$ is a parabolic subgroup.  Characters $\lambda$ of $P(\mathbf C)$ give rise to line bundles $\mathcal{L}(\lambda)$ on $G(\mathbf C)/P(\mathbf C)$.  When is $H^i(G(\mathbf C)/P(\mathbf C),\mathcal{L}(\lambda))$ nonzero, and, in terms of the parabolic $P(\mathbf C)$, which irreducible representations of $G(\mathbf C)$ arise from this construction?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178783/botts-formula-for-grassmannians

Comment: Yes.  The theorem is exactly the same.  The highest weights which appear are the ones that extend to characters of $P$.  The proof is just pushing forward under the obvious map, and noting that those line bundles are trivial on the fibers.

Comment: Also, there is a useful extension for vector bundles corresponding to the irreducible representations of the parabolic subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kostant, *Lie algebra cohomology and the generalized Borel-Weil theorem*, Ann. Math. 74 (1961), 329-387.

W. Schmid, *Homogeneous complex manifolds and representations of semisimple Lie groups*, **Proceedings of the International Congress of Mtahematicians: Helsinki 1978** (ed. O. Lehto) 195-208.

You could also look at R. Baston, M. Eastwood, **The Penrose Transform: Its Interaction with Representation Theory**, Oxford, 1989.

Answer (score 3):

Lars, search for a paper of Kostant ora paper of Griffiths-Schmid,
you will find a complete answer to your question, even when \lambda is just an irreducible representation. best regards